# Disable filter for only 1 visual on custom tooltip Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I was wondering if it would be possible to disable a filter on 1 specific visual on a custom tooltip.
Let me explain with photos:

Desired result with 3 bars:
[image: Power BI bar chart]

Current result with 1 bar:
[image: Power Bi bar chart]

And Current filter:
[image: Power Bi filter]

I'm looking for an option for **1** visual on the custom tooltip like: "Keep all filters: off".

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go on the tab **"Format"**
2. Select **"Edit interactions"**
3. Select the Filter

[image]

4. Now you see these buttons appear on each visual
5. Select this one to disable the filter for this specific visual

[image]

Comment: Yes, Correct: Thank you!